# If a Bean Constructor has an argument of source Object, then how to write the XML config?

Tags: java, xml, spring

A Basic **Notice class**

```
public class Notice {

   public Notice (Object source)
   {
      //some constructor initialization.
   }

}
```

A Special case **OfferNotice** class

```
public class OfferNotice  extends Notice {

   public OfferNotice  (Object source)
   {
      super(source);
      //some constructor initialization.
   }

}
```

A **GenericNoticeRecord** class

```
abstract public class GenericNoticeRecord <E extends Notice> 
{
        abstract public void recordNotice();     
}
```

A Special case **OfferNoticeRecord** class

```
class OfferNoticeRecord extends GenericNoticeRecord <OfferNotice> 
{

    private OfferNotice notice;

    public void setNotice(OfferNotice notice) {
        this.notice= notice;
    }

    public void recordNotice() {        
        // some implementation on Notice
    }


}
```

In **MainService** class

```
public class Mainservice {

    private OfferNoticeRecord offerNoticeRecord;

    public void send()
    {
       offerNoticeRecord.recordNotice();
    }
}
```

In **App** class

```
public class App {

   ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
   serv = context.getBean("MainService");

   serv.send()

}
```

Now how to inject dependency by XML for this sample application?
Now below is what i tried in XML Config

```
<bean id="MainService" class="com.test.MainService">    
    <property name="offerNoticeRecord">
         <ref bean="OfferNoticeRecordBean"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="OfferNoticeRecordBean" class="com.test.OfferNoticeRecord">    
    <property name="notice">
        <ref bean="OfferNoticeBean"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="OfferNoticeBean" class="com.test.OfferNotice">    
    //here is major confusion, constructor is expecting source Object
</bean>
```

Comment: Well, what would you pass if you were creating a `OfferNotice` in code?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the problem is how to *pass* the object reference in XML configuration.

Comment: Check here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators and the part 3.3.1.3. Some examples.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That becomes easy once we know _what_ we want to pass. OP, what is `source` meant to be?

Comment: @Sotiros Actually in program, it would be like `OfferNotice = new OfferNotice(this);` so how to add like this dependency

Comment: It will depend on the client. What is the class of `this`? Or will you try to initialize these beans manually?

Comment: @Luiggi `OfferNotice = new OfferNotice(this);` was previously created directly in the `MainService` but since i wanted to decouple all the dependency, i made it to setters so i could inject by XML.

Comment: Then reference, `ref`, the `MainService` bean in the `OfferNoticeBean` `constructor-arg` element.

Comment: If its only constructor takes arguments it isn't a Bean.